# UNION-ing results from N SQL Server databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I have a SQL Server with hundreds of identical databases. I need to be able to grab a subset of the databases and do a query against the first one, then union that with the second, third and so forth. I need to return a result that is just one set of data from all the selected databases.

I want to *avoid* (if at all possible) doing this with outputting a script and then running that or creating a temp table and inserting values. I am thinking a pointer is my best best, but not really sure....

```
-- doesn't have to be like this, but this is an example of 
-- one way I might attack the problem
DECLARE C_CURSOR CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT [Name] 
    FROM sys.databases 
    WHERE name like 'b%_db'
    ORDER BY name

DECLARE @DB_Name AS NVARCHAR(200)

OPEN C_CURSOR

FETCH NEXT FROM C_CURSOR INTO @DB_Name

WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT @DB_Name AS DbName, P.PersonID, P.FirstName, P.LastName, P.Email    
    FROM People P

    -- UNION?? (doesn't work, but something along the lines of that)?

    FETCH NEXT FROM C_CURSOR INTO @DB_Name
END

CLOSE C_CURSOR
```

I would expect a result that was something like (represented as CSV)

```
DbName, PersonID, FirstName, LastName, Email
DB1, Guid1, Joe, Schmoe, joe@schmoe.com
DB1, Guid2, Jack, Spratt, jack.s@gmail.com
DB2, Guid3, John, Doe, john.doe.lives@gmail.com
```

Comment: You are trying the solve the problem on a wrong way ideally you should merge all those hundreds identical tables to one table..

Comment: I'm not sure what your actual question is here.   Are you asking for opinions?

Comment: Why cant you insert the query results into a table. Create a table and insert the select clause into that table

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid the clear solutions (inserting into a table or temp table) to try for a union? Like, what's the problem with a table that you would like to use a union instead? That seems like your real question, because you obviously know you can't use a union...

Comment: Why are there hundreds of databases? Do you have a multi-tenant application or did you try to "partition" the data? If you used different table partitions instead of different databases you wouldn't need to write anything special.

Comment: You should pull all the data into a single table. It's no different than what SQL Server itself would do with a big UNION ALL query - it would have to store all the data in tempdb before it started returning any rows.

Comment: You could automate *and* speed up the process though if you pulled new/changed rows from the target tables periodically into the reporting table. Using GUIDs for keys is unfortunate because you can't use their values to find new rows, unless you use the NEWSQUENTIALID() function to produce the keys. You can use SQL Server's [Change Tracking feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) to find and load modified rows

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, everyone! To answer a few of the questions:
1) merge tables: This is not an option in the current structure. These are all client dbs and they need to stay as separate dbs for now. But I need to gather info across a subset of them
2) I *can* insert the results into a temp table, if that's really my only option. Seems "hacky," though. Maybe I'm wrong, but I have to manually create a table to match my dataset, insert into it and the delete it. If I want to expand my query or change an output name, I have to change it in 2 place (or 3, if I don't select * the results)

Comment: 3) Yes, it's a multi-tenant db situation. Moving forward we may end up with a single database, but that's not how it is now
This is not a reporting thing, and I can obviously do the temp table, but my (naive?) gut thought there should be a way to do this in one run with clean SQL. Just to gather results across N databases into a single result set. Maybe that's just not a thing, though?

Oh, and no, I'm not asking for opinions, per se, but more for advice on how to accomplish this. If my only option is to use a temp table, so be it. Just hoped there was a cleaner way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Usual approach would have been to use Temp Tables or consolidate them as a Multi-Tenant Table, however here is a sample workaround:

```
declare @Complete varchar(max)
select @Complete = coalesce(@Complete+' Union ', '') + concat('select ''' + [name] + ''', P.PersonID, P.FirstName, P.LastName, P.Email  from ',[name],'..','People P') from sys.databases where name like 'b%_db' ORDER BY name

exec (@Complete)
```

hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks, @Bemidelzz! Interesting solution and yes, it works. 
My actual query is 100X more complicated than the sample I sent, though, so I am realizing that I would probably have a hard time getting it into this format properly and then debugging it in this format, once I have it.
So I guess I'm coming around to the idea of a temp table, after all

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temp table

```
CREATE TABLE #results (
  DbName sysname not null COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT,
  PersonID uniqueidentifier not null,
  FirstName nvarchar(128) NOT NULL COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT,
  LastName nvarchar(128) NOT NULL COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT,
  Email nvarchar(255) NOT NULL COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
)
```

In your cursor, INSERT the SELECT results into this temp table.

In the end SELECT * FROM #results;

Comment: Adjust the data types based on your real database.

Comment: Thanks, @PeterHe. Per my description, I'm trying to avoid having to create (and maintain the structure of) a temp table. I know it's an option, but as my query changes, I have to constantly update the table, too, and also deal with inserts and selects from it. Seems like there *should* be a way to just get a select that grows and grows over each iteration of new databases, no?

Comment: After reading all the great comments, I am coming around to a temp table. Thanks, PeterHe.